# C++ Binary Search - Array Position Variables

Tags: c++, binary-search

This should just be a silly little general question (if I can word it well).  While looking at my professor's example and watching YouTube videos, I noticed when people setup a binary search, they DECLARE but don't DEFINE the variables for the array positions (e.g. first, mid, last OR low, mid, high).

Piece of Prof's Example:

```
int bsearch(const int list[], int first, int last, int searchItem){
  if(first <= last){
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    .......
```

How/Why does this work without setting a value for first/last/mid?

---

Alright, these responses make sense.  But, in the context of my professor's example, I'm having difficulty understanding where this happens.  I see where he returns bsearch() with what I would think are still undefined parameters and later calls binarySearch(), but with only 3 parameters.  I see I've been downvoted; I'm not sure why or where this person expects me to turn with programming questions.  Anyway here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int bsearch(const int list[], int first, int last, int searchItem)
{
  if(first <= last) {
    int mid = (first + last) / 2;
    if(list[mid] == searchItem)
      return mid;
    else
      if(list[mid] > searchItem)
        return bsearch(list, first, mid-1, searchItem);
      else
        return bsearch(list, mid+1, last, searchItem);
  }
  else
    return -1;
}

// Non-recursive shell for the recursive binary search function.
// This function does not use "first" and "last" as its parameters.
int binarySearch(const int list[], int listLength, int searchItem)
{
  return bsearch(list, 0, listLength-1, searchItem);
}

int main() // testing recursive binarySearch function
{
  int a[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
  int item;
  cout << "Search item? ";
  cin >> item;
  cout << binarySearch(a, 10, item) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The values are provided when the function is called.

Comment: `mid` is defined. Function parameters are declared, and will be defined when you call it.

Comment: Okay, I think I realize that "last" and "searchItem" come from: "cout<<binarySearch(a, 10, item).....", but I guess I still don't understand how "first" is determined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We define `mid` with the statement on the third line:

```
int mid = (first + last) / 2;
```

As for the others, we define `first` and `last` by calling the function. For example:

```
a = bsearch(my_list, 1, 100, 55);
```

according to `int bsearch(const int list[], int first, int last, int searchItem)` this equivalent to saying

```
int first = 1;
int last = 100;
int searchitem = 55;
```

We do this partly because we don't always want to define the same values for every binary search, but much more importantly it allows us to call the binary search [**recursively**](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D2N36Up4/).

### So what about your professor's example?

Let's follow the function calls, and see what happens!

In `main()` we have this line of code:

```
cout << binarySearch(a, 10, item) << endl;
```

When we look at binarySearch, the structure of the function is as follows:

```
int binarySearch(const int list[], int listLength, int searchItem)
```

According to the previous example, you could also think of this as

```
const int list[] = a; //for now you can think of it as "= (the contents of a)", though it works a little different in reality
int listLength = 10;
int searchItem = item;
```

But now we make ANOTHER function call:

```
return bsearch(list, 0, listLength-1, searchItem);
```

But wait! Based off our last example, and knowing the structure for bsearch (`bsearch(const int list[], int first, int last, int searchItem)`) we can see these variables are also defined!

In a way, you can think of it like this!

```
//== main() ==

   int a[] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20};
   int item;
   cin >> item;


//== int const list[] v       v int searchItem ==
//==     binarysearch(a, 10, item)             ==
//==       int listLength ^                    ==

   const int list[] = a;
   int listLength = 10;
   int searchItem = item;

//== int const list[] v          v int last                     ==
//==         bsearch(list, 0, listLength -1, searchItem)        ==
//==             int first ^                   ^ int searchItem ==

   const int list_bsearch = list;
   int first = 0;
   int last = listLength -1;
   int searchItem_bsearch = searchItem;
```

**SO**, the way we define `searchItem`, for example, you just follow the definitions.

searchItem (bsearch) = searchItem (binarySearch) = item

Notice binarySearch and bsearch are different functions with different parameters. The reason behind "why do this" has to do with recursion and is worth another question entirely.

### Still stuck?

Here's a really simple example:

```
int fooAdd(int a, int b){

   //a and b are ints
   //by calling fooAdd(2, five) we set a = 2, and b = five (which was an int that happened to have the bvalue 5;

   return a +b;
}

int main(){
   int five = 5;   
   cout << fooAdd(2, five);
   return 0;
}
```

---

P.S. A response to your "I see I've been downvoted; I'm not sure why or where this person expects me to turn with programming questions" quip.

Many people at stack overflow love helping you out, but sometimes the question isn't written in a very clear way, or there's too many mini-questions to really help you out.

Don't think that by downvoting, we're discouraging you from asking questions. Try to imagine how your question could be asked **better**!

Comment: This makes theoretical sense, but I can't discern where this happens in the context of my professor's example.

Comment: @shane, I'm gonna try to work out my answer to better explain it ok? Hold tight!

Comment: Wow.  I thank you greatly for the thorough response.  I'm studying for a test and I couldn't progress any further until I understood how this worked (just how my mind is wired).  Also, I'll try and word my questions better from here on.  I put a lot of effort into wording - it's just sometimes I don't understand the topic enough to even really know what or how to ask.  The only reason I even said anything is I was nearly banned from asking questions a while back.  As an IT student, that would be a major loss.  I'm definitely not a troll and I try to be as thoughtful as possible. Thanks again.

Comment: @shane Awesome! Glad I could help, and you can help me (and anyone asking a similar question) by accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are passed in to the function when it is called. For example:

```
int main()
{
    int list[] = [1,2,3,4,5];
    cout << bsearch(list, 0, 4, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the provided function is recursion. Therefore, BEFORE you enter recursion (function calling itself), you have to call that function from somewhere else (for example: you call bsearch from main, then it is in the main where first and last are set to some values)

```
int main ()
{
   bsearch(list, 0, 4, 2);
}
```